# Transit visa for Nepali citizen in Guangzhou

Tags: transit, transit-visas, china, nepali-citizens, china-southern-airlines

I am Nepali passport holder traveling to Nepal with China Southern Airlines from New York. I have 6 hours transit (both back and to Nepal) in Guangzhou, China. I am not getting out of the airport. I wonder if I am eligible for 24-hour visa free transit. I am posting this because I saw nothing on this specific airport or China Southern Airlines online. Is Nepali passport has some rules on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this website](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/free-transit-24hour.htm) (which has proved so far accurate), you can get the 24-hour direct transit visa.